# JDOM - How to create an XML with internal DTD declaration?

Tags: java, xml, dtd, internal, jdom

I need to create an XML by JDOM with an internal DTD declaration.
By now I was creating it with an external DTD and this is the code:

```
public static void makeFile(Element rootElement, String pathDtd){

    Document documento = new Document();
    DocType type = new DocType(rootElement.getName(), pathDtd);
    documento.setDocType(type);
    documento.setRootElement(rootElement);

    XMLOutputter xmlOutputter = new XMLOutputter();
    xmlOutputter.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
    /* Validazione xml ottenuto */
    String xmlOttenuto = xmlOutputter.outputString(documento);
    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder(XMLReaders.DTDVALIDATING);

    try {
        Document documentoCorretto = builder.build(new StringReader(xmlOttenuto));
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(rootElement.getName()+".xml"));
        xmlOutputter.output(documentoCorretto, fileOutputStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1){
        System.err.println(e1);
    } catch(IOException e2){
        System.err.println(e2);
    } catch (JDOMException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DocType` structs are able to contain both external and internal references. You can add an internal subset by calling [`setInternalSubset()`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/DocType.html#setInternalSubset(java.lang.String)) on the doctype. The input value must be the string representing the full declaration. JDOM does not do an internal 'model' of the doctype - it treats it as a "blob".

Note that you can create the DocType without an external reference using the constructor [`DocType(String)`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/DocType.html#DocType(java.lang.String))

Comment: This way it only writes: "<!DOCTYPE rootElement>" without the full dtd declaration. What if I would like to make it write the full dtd?

Comment: Like this: <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE tutorials [
<!ELEMENT tutorials (tutorial)+>
<!ELEMENT tutorial (name,url)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT url (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST tutorials type CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
<tutorials type="web">
  <tutorial>
    <name>XML Tutorial</name>
    <url>http://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial</url>
  </tutorial>
  <tutorial>
    <name>HTML Tutorial</name>
    <url>http://www.quackit.com/html/tutorial</url>
  </tutorial>
</tutorials>

Comment: Then call `type.setInternalSubset("<!ELEMENT tutorials (tutorial)+> <!ELEMENT tutorial (name,url)> <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)> <!ELEMENT url (#PCDATA)> <!ATTLIST tutorials type CDATA #REQUIRED>")`